# Bootstrap layout with variable height column content inside a row and properly wrapping them on different screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

[image]
Need to position the block properly using bootstrap4, based on the screen size. In larger screen, all should be in a row, but when the screen size is reduced to medium, the right most block should come below the first one. I tried using d-none class and it works. But, need to repeat the code. So, just wanted to make sure, is it a proper way to do so. Thanks!

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4" style="background-color: red; height: 60px">
    <p>Bread Crump</p>
    <p>Bread Crump</p>
 <div class="d-none d-md-block d-lg-none mt-2" style="background-color: pink; height: 100px">
  <p>List</p>
  <p>List</p>
  <p>List</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4" style="background-color: green; height: 150px">
    <p>Name</p>
    <p>Name</p>
    <p>Name</p>
    <p>Name</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 d-md-none d-lg-block" style="background-color: pink; height: 100px">
    <p>List</p>
    <p>List</p>
    <p>List</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper way of doing this in Bootstrap 4 is using the `order` classes to re-order the columns at different breakpoints like so:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4" style="background-color: red;">
        <p>Bread Crump</p>
        <p>Bread Crump</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4" style="background-color: green; height: 150px">
        <p>Name</p>
        <p>Name</p>
        <p>Name</p>
        <p>Name</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 order-md-2 order-lg-3" style="background-color: pink; height: 100px">
        <p>List</p>
        <p>List</p>
        <p>List</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `order-md-2` class says: You go to place 2 on medium (md) screens and above (as well as below).

The `order-lg-3` class says: You go to place 3 on large (lg) screens and above.

Oh, and of course, if you re-arrange the HTML a bit, you can get away with using just one `order` class instead of two like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4" style="background-color: red;">
        <p>Bread Crump</p>
        <p>Bread Crump</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 order-md-3" style="background-color: pink; height: 100px">
        <p>List</p>
        <p>List</p>
        <p>List</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4" style="background-color: green; height: 150px">
        <p>Name</p>
        <p>Name</p>
        <p>Name</p>
        <p>Name</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

That `order-md-3` class in the second code snippet tells the second column:

"You are normally second here but from the medium (md) breakpoint onwards you're gonna be third!"

And of course, I could have treated the second column in the first code snippet the same way (using the `order-md-3` class). Those are just different options.

Finally, you can also use the `order-md-last` class on the second column to tell it to go last from the medium breakpoint onwards.

Comment: Also note: bootstrap 4.0.0-beta.2 is obsolete now. BS4 final is current.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It works if the height of first and second column are same but if the first one is smaller then second one, gap is created between them.

Comment: No gaps if you use my code. Please copy and paste my snippet and see for yourself. The gap was there because you had hardcoded something. I had removed that in my code snippets.

Comment: You have not provided the height for the first block and it is taking the height of the second block. try adding height of 70px to first and you will notice the difference.

Comment: Well, that's the flex-row at work there. You have that gap in your original code also. So, the possible options are: 1) Have the gap at the top of the first column instead at the bottom. 2) Have the first column centered i.e. equal gap at the top and at the bottom or 3) Have it stretch out the way you've seen already.

Comment: Another option would be, of course, to let them stack on top of each other in a column, but you said you wanted a row. In a flex row, those are the only options. Align top, align bottom, align center or stretch out.

Comment: One could say this is a limitation of the flexbox itself. That's because flexbox is one-dimensional. In css grid you don't have that limitation because css grid is 2-dimensional. But Bootstrap is based on flexbox and does not (yet) incorporate css grid. The css grid would have allowed eliminating that gap even without stretching it out.

Comment: However, normally, you wouldn't want that behavior that the css grid would have allowed. Because normally, you want things to be aligned in a row on a website. What you have in mind would break the visual alignment of a row. So, it would only be useful for special cases but generally would not be desirable for a website.

Comment: Also, css grid is brand new. Much newer than flexbox and therefore only works in the newest browsers (defaulting to mobile first view in older browsers).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions!